# Using rvest to scrape from password protected website

Tags: rvest

I have been sucessfully using rvest, on a HP EliteBook (running Windows 7), to access data on a password protected website for some time.

The code I was successsfully running is:

## Load required packages

library(rvest)

```
# Connect to confidential live report
URL <- url("http://username:password@urlofpasswordprotectedsite")
# Read in data
RawData <- read_html(URL)
# Identify the table
RawDataTable <- html_nodes(RawData, "table")
RawDataTable1 <- html_table(RawDataTable[1], fill = TRUE)
# Make data.frame
RawData <- as.data.frame(RawData)
```

However after attempting to scrape data now via R, I am faced with the following error:

`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : cannot open the connection`

This error happened when I worked on a Mac, but was content to stick with the HP for running analysis. I am able to load the following without issue:

```
htmlpage <- read_html("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=42.27925753000045&lon=-71.41616624299962#.V17UH-IrKHs")
```

Is this error due to my machine or is there a recent update to the rvest package that may be throwing the error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using:

```
html_session("http://username:password@urlofpasswordprotectedsite")
```

in place of:

```
url("http://username:password@urlofpasswordprotectedsite")
```